# Unzip 1million+ archives into correct folder structure

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unzip

Firstly I am completely new to Linux as I set up an AWS Ubuntu instance for this project so be kind.

I have downloaded approximately 1 million .zip files containing .csv's in the following folder structure (financial data):

```
Main Folder
├── Exchange1
│   ├── Pair1
│   │   └── Month
│   │       └── .Zips
│   └── PairN
│       └── Month
│           └── .Zips
└── ExchangeN
    ├── Pair1
    │   └── Month
    │       └── .Zips
    ├── Pair2
    │   └── Month
    │       └── .Zips
    └── PairN
        └── Month
            └── .Zips
```

and I would like to extract every zip under it's parent `Pair` folder disregarding the month folder so that the new structure would look like this:

```
Main Folder
├── Exchange1
│   ├── Pair1
│   │   └── Extracted .csv's     
│   └── PairN
│       └── Extracted .csv's
└── ExchangeN
    ├── Pair1
    │   └── Extracted .csv's
    ├── Pair2
    │   └── Extracted .csv's
    └── PairN
        └── Extracted .csv's
```

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: From the main folder, how would you unzip one file into PairN?

Comment: each .zip has the file name `EXCHANGE_PAIR_trades_YYYY_MM_DD` that may be useful for this?

Comment: [mcve] Please show some real names. The Ns from EXCHANGE and PAIR (or is it Pair?) are not part of the filenames? The numbers in the path run from 1 to N without dash or underline or leading zeros? Exchange743 for example and analog for Pair? Apart from the date, everything is uppercase? The target dir should literally be named `Extracted`? Does it already exist? Do the zip-files contain paths?

Answer (score 0):

Run this script in your main folder.

```
#! /bin/sh 

#find all nested zip files and assign it to an array    
files=( $(find . -iname "*zip*" -exec echo {} \;) )
for i in "${files[@]}"
do
 #extract the path to unzip the archive
 path=$(echo "$i" | cut -d '/' -f-3)
 unzip $i -d $path
done
```

Please be careful when you run this. Assigning the output of `ls/find` to an array can have weird and unexpected consequences when the directory contains filenames with a newline, pipe etc.

Quoting Greg

> Unix allows almost any character in a filename, including whitespace, newlines, commas, pipe symbols, and pretty much anything else you'd ever try to use as a delimiter except NUL.

Reference 
1. [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing which might possibly work is:

```
find . -iname "*.zip" -execdir unzip -d ../ {} ";"
```

issued from Main Folder/.

But first try with an echo for visual control:

```
find ./Exchange1/Pair1 -iname "*.zip" -execdir echo unzip -d ../ {} ";"
```

If this looks promising, make a copy of some test folders and try over there:

```
find ./Exchange1/ -iname "*.zip" -execdir unzip -d ../ {} ";"
```

If it works, take the real files.